# Are LVM Physical Extents the equivalent of block group in standard partitions?

Tags: lvm

LVM divides up the physical volume in PEs which are the smallest unit of data that can be written meaning a 3Mb file on a PV with 4Mb PE will still occupy 4Mb. This to me sounds very similar to the concept of block groups in standard partitions which are made out of a integral multiple of sector. So am I understanding this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> LVM divides up the physical volume in PEs which are the smallest unit of data that can be written

This is about allocation units for metadata management within LVM itself. It has nothing to do with how data is read and written by the filesystem on top. That works just like any other block device at single sector resolution.

It's the same with traditional partitioning. Although sure, it *technically* allows you to put them on any sector offsets, in practice you will probably want to follow MiB alignment rules, and so you could consider traditional partitions to have a PE size of 1MiB. But that doesn't stop you from reading/writing in 4 KiB or 512 byte sectors.

Even if you set the PE size to something much larger (e.g. 128M or 1G) that just means you won't be able to create a LV smaller than 128M or 1G (1 PE) and all your LV will be multiple of PE in size. For the filesystem itself, nothing changes.

You can also change the PE size on the fly any time you like, provided all your LV are aligned to the new PE size.

The PE size has more of a practical effect when you use snapshots or thin volumes or pvmove. LVM will clone the entire PE for the snapshot or allocate/free entire PE for the thin volume or mirror one PE at a time for the pvmove.

So the PE size can affect performance for specific LVM operations. But again that's just how LVM handles things internally. If you rarely change LVM metadata then it pretty much does not matter.

If in doubt, just stick with the default setting and don't worry about it.

> meaning a 3Mb file on a PV with 4Mb PE will still occupy 4Mb.

So this is a yes and no. If you have a thin volume that allocated PE only where needed / when written to, then yes if you write a 3MB file somewhere, and you have PEs of 128M, then that 3MB file would "use 128M of space" in quotes.

But it would not occupy it, the other 125M are still "free space" in the filesystem so there's room for plenty of other 3M files within the same PE.

On the other hand if you use tiny PE size you might run into extreme fragmentation on the LVM layer. So smaller PE isn't necessarily better either.